# Inaccuracy for FEM for 3D Heat Equation

Tags: finite-element-method, heat-equation

I'm simulating the heat transfer within a cylindrical rod, with external heating from its sides.

```
\[CapitalOmega] = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.1}}, 0.1];
bc1 = NeumannValue[(10000 t)/1.38, x^2 + y^2 > 0.1^2 - 0.001];
bc2 = NeumannValue[0, z == 0.1];
bc3 = NeumannValue[0, z == 0];
ic1 = T[x, y, z, 0] == 200;

heat= 1521740*D[T[x,y,z,t],t]-Laplacian[T[x,y,z,t],{x,y,z}]==bc1+bc2+bc3;
sol = NDSolve[{heat, ic1}, {T}, {x, y, z} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], {t, 0, 10}, Method ->{"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement","MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.00001}, "InterpolationOrder" -> {T -> 2}}}}]
TPlot[x_, y_, z_, t_] := T[x, y, z, t] /. sol[[1, 1]]
Plot[TPlot[0.1, 0, z, 10], {z, 0, 0.1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

When I plot the temperature along a vertical slice, it seems that theres a huge variation in temperature which seems wrong. Does anyone know whats wrong? (I suspect its some issue related to the fineness of the mesh but im not sure)

Comment: Can you give some context on the physics here?

Comment: It’s a solid cylindrical pipe being heated from its sides (not the two circular flat faces) with heat flux of 10000t. I’m solving it using the 3D heat equation and cannot use the 2D axisymmetric one for other reasons

Comment: I was wondering about the physical material properties. Thermal condition, specific heat etc.

Comment: The density is 2500, specific heat is 840, conductivity is 1.38. All quantities are in SI base form

Answer (score 3):

**modified**

With some modification your code evalautes:

- change bc1 to constant flux `bc1 = NeumannValue[(10000 (*t*))/1.38, 0 < z < 1/10];`
- bc2,bc3 might be omitted
- set `MeshOrder->1` instead of `InterpolationOrder`
- use rational paramaters
- **check the time scale of your problem(simulationtime >>10)**

Try

```
tsim=500;
\[CapitalOmega] = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1/10}}, 1/10];
bc1 = NeumannValue[(10000 (*t*))/1.38, 0 < z < 1/10];

ic1 = T[x, y, z, 0] == 200;

heat = 1521740 *D[T[x, y, z, t], t] -Laplacian[T[x, y, z, t], {x, y, z}] ==bc1 ;

sol = NDSolveValue[{heat, ic1}, 
T, {x, y, z} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], {t, 0, tsim}, 
Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines","SpatialDiscretization"->   {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> { "MaxCellMeasure" -> "Length" -> 1/10/10 , 
      "MeshOrder" -> 1 }}}}]

Plot3D[ sol[0.1 , 0, z, t ] , {z, 0, 0.1}, {t, 0, tsim},PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {z, t, "sol"}]
```

[image]

In the plot temperature equalization along z is visible now.

But still flux at the, examplary, face  `z==0` doesn't vanish as expected for `t>0`:

```
disk = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 < (1/10)^2 , {x, y}];
Plot3D[Evaluate[Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0][sol][x, y, 0, #]],Element[{x, y}, disk], PlotRange -> All] &[1]
```

[image]

Comment: It seems weird to me that there’s such a significant variation in temperature along the z axis since the pipe is being uniformly  heated from z = 0 to z = 0.1

Comment: @Lucas The pipe is uniformly heated, but you force no flux at `z==0, z==1/10` That's why temprature at the flat faces is higher than inside `0<z<1/10`!

Comment: the pipe should only be heated at the sides and not the flat faces. I’m not sure if the no flux condition at z=0 and z=0.1 affects the flux from the side in any way.

Comment: For inner points there is a heatflow in positive and negative z-direction, whereas at the flat sides the flux is one-sided

Comment: Is the heat flow in the negative and positive z direction because of the way the BCs are implemented? Intuitively there should be no heat flow in the z direction

Answer (score 1):

This seems not to be an issue, is just how the system behaves due to the boundary conditions applied.
You can visualize the region boundary of your geometry, in this case, it is a 2D surface.

```
    bIDs = mesh["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"];
Manipulate[Show[
  mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" ->
     Directive[Opacity[0.2], FaceForm[LightBlue], EdgeForm[]]]],
  mesh["Edgeframe"],
  mesh["Wireframe"[ElementMarker == bIDs[[id]], 
    "MeshElementStyle" -> 
     Directive[FaceForm[LightGray], EdgeForm[]]]]
  ], {{id, 1, "ElementMarker ID"}, 1, Length[bIDs], 1, 
  Appearance -> "Open"}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image: Boundary surface]

You will notice that this surface includes the contour of the flat surfaces at the bottom and top, which is how it works. That is why one should be careful about how boundary conditions are applied, the boundary conditions should always be consistent with each other and also with the initial conditons. In this case, the thermally insulated boundary conditions at the flat surfaces are causing this behaviour.

In 3D regions and in curve regions I prefer to use ElementMarkers. The ElementMarker for this particular surface is has the number ID 1.

I used a more refined mesh, but this is not an issue of a mesh refinement, the same behaviour is seen.
The mesh I used:

```
\[CapitalOmega] = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.1}}, 0.1];
mesh = ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega], "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0000001]
```

Variables and parameters used:

```
vars = {T[x, y, z, t], t, {x, y, z}};
pars = <|"MassDensity" -> 2500, "SpecificHeatCapacity" -> 840, 
   "ThermalConductivity" -> 1.38*IdentityMatrix[3]|>;
```

Equation:

```
op = HeatTransferPDEComponent[vars, pars];
```

Boundary and initial conditions:

```
bc1 = HeatFluxValue[ElementMarker == 1 , vars, 
   pars, <|"HeatFlux" -> (10000 t)/1.38|>];
ic1 = T[x, y, z, 0] == 200;
```

Solution:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{op == bc1, ic1}, 
  T, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh, {t, 0, 10}];
Plot[sol[0.1, 0, z, 10], {z, 0, 0.1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Temperature plot at x=0.1, y=0 and 0<=z<=0.1

```
Plot[sol[0.1, 0, z, 10], {z, 0, 0.1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Temperature plot at -0.1<=x<=0.1, y=0, z=0.1:

```
Plot[sol[x, 0, 0.1, 10], {x, -0.1, 0.1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

From the last plot you can see that the temperatures at the perimeter of the flat surfaces are higher.

Also, if the simulation time is increased, the same behaviour will be seen at any time step.
In the following documentation link you can see a verification test between a 3D heat transfer and a 2D axis model: PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransferVerificationTests#700297701